# Why NGinx don't pass the HOST?

Tags: nginx

I need to use NGinx as a proxy to another HTTP proxy, and it doesn't works because it doesn't sent the HOST of original url, only the path.

If I perform the request with curl it works and the dump is

```
curl --proxy http://localhost:81 http://sample.com/sample

http://sample.com/some-path
{ host: 'sample.com' }
```

If I perform the request with NGinx with the following config - it doesn't works and the dump is (the domain in the path is missing)

```
upstream proxies {server localhost:81;}
location / {  
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_pass http://proxies;
}

/some-path
{ host: 'sample.com' }
```

How to make NGinx to pass the whole path?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NGinx doesn't works with HTTP Proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030294/nginx-doesnt-works-with-http-proxy)

Comment: I deleted that question, description in this one is better.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to add other proxy, for example DeleGate. Yes, NGinx won't pass the HOST properly, but the DeleGate fixes that.

```
Your Browser or App -> (NGinx -> DeleGate) -> whatever other proxy or app...
```